# Defining associations in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have three tables in my database. They are **Student**, **Subject** and **Mark**. **Student** has these fields: **id**, **name**, **address**. **Subject** has these fields: **id**, **name**. And **Mark** has these fields **id**, **studentId**, **subjectId** and **mark**. So, here I have these associations like **Student** can have **many subject** and **one subject** has **one mark**. So, how can I define these relations in MVC pattern like placing them in Model and Store. I want to display the information like student_name, student_address, subject_name and marks in my grid panel. But I having trouble associating them in Model and Stores.

Comment: Their are lots of examples out there. What did you come up with yourself?

Comment: I got no clue so I just went on defining separate model and store for my required data and passing those data from the backend

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs of [the model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) and [the reader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader). There you will find enough information to get you started.

After reading the docs you can take a look at the tutorials of [MiamiCoder](http://miamicoder.com/2015/how-ext-js-many-to-many-associations-work/), [ModusCreate](http://moduscreate.com/associations-in-ext-js-5/) and [this one](http://blog.cubettech.com/a-glimpse-of-ext-js-5-model-store)..

Answer (score 0):

I just made sometime ago a fiddle that show how association works. You can see json example also.

When you catch the basics, rest should be easier to understand.

[How associations works - Fiddle - by example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rat)